# When is Google Drive going to be released on Ubuntu?

Tags: cloud, dropbox, google

Does anyone have any information on when Google Drive App will be released for Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: I dont understand your question.  Is google drive not accessed from the browser?  thats how I use it in ubuntu.  Or do you mean an app?

Comment: Yes, I think the question relates to an app. The app, in MS Windows, allows sync as well. For now, I'm accessing it via the browser. If you use Chrome, there's an extension that can be installed that will effectively "sync" your data in the cloud with a local version that can **only** be viewed (and not edited), when off-line.

Comment: The only answer for this is "When it's ready". There is probably nobody here who can answer this question, and if is anyone, they would be unable to tell you because of how Google works.

Comment: Really the answer is: Ask Google, since only Google will know when they will release it.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the only thing that is known so far: http://omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/google-drive-is-coming-to-linux/

But there is some temporary solution available until the official client comes to Ubuntu: http://omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/google-drive-is-coming-to-linux/

Answer (score 0):

While it's still under development, the [`fuse-google-drive`](https://github.com/jcline/fuse-google-drive/) project has made some good progress towards a filesystem driver for Google Drive. Also, though I've not tried it myself, some have reported that [`google-docs-fs`](http://www.zimbio.com/Ubuntu+Linux/articles/gVdrI310RS3/Access+Google+Drive+Ubuntu) can be used to get access to Google Drive from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any information on when google will release google drive for linux, however I recommend to ask for it on the google drive feedback form, which can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dG45cFM2TGRHUjhTRzkzay12eEtuWFE6MA#gid=0):